# Proper way to pass array to shader in three.js

Tags: arrays, three.js, shader

I have a simple program where I am trying to pass an array of fixed values (essentially a lookup table) to a shader.  The calling code looks like this:

```
    var displacement = [];

    for ( var y=0; y<46; y++ ) {
        for ( var x=0; x<46; x++ ) {
            var sVal = Math.sin((((x/5.0)*40.0)/360.0)*Math.PI*2.0);
            var index = x + 46 * y;
            displacement[index] =  sVal;
        }
    }

    planeGeometry.addAttribute( 'displacement', new THREE.BufferAttribute( displacement, 1 ) );

    var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms:       uniforms,   // pass the "uniforms" vars
        //attributes:     attributes,   // and the attributes
        side:THREE.DoubleSide,      // want the texture on both sides of the wave
        vertexShader:   vs,         // pointers to the shaders
        fragmentShader: fs
    });
```

The shader looks like this:

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying vec2        vUv;
        attribute float     displacement;
        uniform float       amplitude;
        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            vec3 newPosition = position + normal * vec3(displacement * amplitude);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
```

Prior to r72, I passed the array as an attribute in the constructor for the shader material, but now it has to be passed as a bufferGeometry attribute.  The old way worked, but now I get

[.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

I've tried a whole bunch of ways to do this, but none of them work.  Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a typed-array for you displacement array, instead of a JS array.

```
var displacement = new Float32Array( size );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Worked like a charm!  So simple!  Thanks!  You guys at three.js rock!